# Bootstrap - reversing my navbar to Right-to-Left

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-4

Im trying to make a navbar but I need it to be from Right to Left cause its in Hebrew.

I tried making a responsive Navbar Where all the linked buttons are on the Left and Going Right.
And a Brand on the Right side.
And they collapse on Small devices.

Well I cant get it to reverse and I also sometimes get an issue where on small devices the Brand and the Collapse button collide in the middle of the navbar.

Comment: kindly show your efforts. what have you tried?

Comment: Give me 1 min ill get it

Comment: Sorry I cant Ctrl-Z enough to go there .I tried lots of stuff mainly putting all the nav items inside a flexbox which did reverse them but I couldnt position them and the Brand moved to the left side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I fixed it by adding:

```
body{
    direction: rtl;
}
```

to my css...

Thanks for the help and sorry for misleading you by my wrong title D:

Comment: God bless you! I'm also building a website in Hebrew and couldn't find a solution until now. אז מלא תודההה

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe you can use media query with the smallest query eg media query
example:


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Center</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Right</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

@media (min-width: 240px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
```

Comment: I tried pasting your code instead of mine and when I tested it I had a small button on the left and when I click on it I have the Left and Right links underneath it and both Center links in the middle a bit lower then Right and Left. Did I do something wrong? I pasted the Media query in my css which launches after the Bootstrap css.

Comment: I made a mistake in my post, I meant Right to Left.

Comment: what do you mean this questions ......
I tried making a responsive Navbar Where all the linked buttons are on the Left and Going Right. And a Brand on the Right side. And they collapse on Small devices. ??? 

mybe solution small device 
use media query css

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" style="direction: rtl;">         
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```